How to put "hashtag #" as a superscript in Python?
Is there any way to put "hashtag #" as a superscript in Python? It is possible for other strings using Unicode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts), but I couldn't find anything for hashtag.

Unclear what you're trying to achieve? You want to use a superscript # in Python source code?

Just to be clear, # is called a "hash" character, not a hashtag.

Simple answer is that it does not exists. Superscript # isn't used in mathematical equations. It sounds like you want to produce formattet text, therefore you should be generating HTML, or LaTeX or a docx file, etc.

Python does not have its own character set or its own text formatting engine. It can generate Unicode text, or (with the assistance of appropriate libraries as necessary) it can generate document formats such as Word or HTML, that have a superscript function.
Depending on your intentions, you might be able to use the hashtag look-alike, U+266F ♯ MUSIC SHARP SIGN.
If not, please provide more information about your task. Someone might be able to provide a more suitable solution using the formatted document approach.

Thanks for the reply. Yes, using the sharp sign is an option.
